# Introducing html tags into string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a string which looks something like this:

```
some text [different text]
```

Using C# is it possible to insert some html tags so that resulting string would be

```
some text [<b>different text</b>]
```

It would have to cope with instances where there are no square brackets.

Comment: Yes. You can...

Comment: can you explain "It would have to cope with instances where there are no square brackets?" Do you have some more examples of strings you would like to work with?

Comment: The question in the current form is unanswerable. We have to guess about all the rules that might apply. What to do with `[aaa` for example? Should it also add tags around it?

Comment: Can you tell us what marks the start of `different text`? Will the `some text` always be fixed and same?

Comment: BBCode? RegEx? A simple string replace? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var str = "some text [different text]";
var html = str.Replace("[", "[<b>").Replace("]", "</b>]");
```

Comment: If you downvote my answer (which works correctly and answers the question), **at least** leave a comment to explain why you did it.

Comment: Hopefully all the upvotes on your comment will counter that downvote. All of us who've suffered the same will be upvoting it. :)